# PrimeFaces Selectors (PFS) using Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]

Tags: jquery, primefaces, jquery-selectors, attributes

I'm trying to use `PFS` to select elements for `processing/updating`. It works fine in case I use e.g. a `styleClass` for the selection.

```
<p:commandButton actionListener="#{testBean.testAction}" value="Submit test"
    process="@this @(.processStyleClass)"
/>
```

But I cannot get it working when using the attribute contains selector (used the maxlength as an example here):

```
<p:inputText value="#{testBean.test}"
    maxlength="4"/>

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{testBean.testAction}" 
    value="Submit test"
    process="@this @([maxlength*='4'])"/>
```

But when I use the selector directly in the console, I can select the input field.

Do you have any working example of selecting by attribute containing with `PFS`?

Kind regards,
jose

*Primefaces 5.1,  Mojarra 2.2.7*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using quotation marks in the attribute selector is causing the issues as it renders the command button as follows (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
<button id="mainForm:j_idt21"      
    onclick="PrimeFaces.ab({s:'mainForm:j_idt21',p:'mainForm:j_idt21 @([maxlength*='4'])'});return false;" 
    type="submit">Submit test
</button>
```

Remove the single quotation mark in the selector to have a proper rendering and working selectors for the process and update attributes:

```
<p:inputText value="#{testBean.test}"
    maxlength="4"/>

<p:commandButton actionListener="#{testBean.testAction}" 
    value="Submit test"
    process="@this @([maxlength*=4])"/>
```